# Why is the value of the ETH in this transaction different to the actual amount of ETH/WETH that was spent buying this coin on Uniswap?

Tags: transactions, ether, etherscan, uniswap, internal-transactions

Would be nice if someone could explain what's happened here and how this can be done.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5abeef45172aef786142f24b64fff5308fe22b8d520ec8335e6ff1484fc63816

Comment: Please share the actual link to the explorer, not a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trade is for about 0.02 WETH to another token. The user sent 0.1 Eth along with the transaction, of which about 0.02 Eth was used for the actual trade. The rest was sent to Uniswap, but was not utilized in the trade - I'm not 100% sure what happened to the rest but probably it was just returned to the sender.

Comment: I see.. If that was the case then why did my transaction, which was of lesser value to 0.1 ETH, rejected? In the sense of, why didn't my trade do the same thing where it uses a certain amount for the actual trade and any excess amounts of ETH gets returned.     https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07fdf7a1aed7fb3e313a20c4a5954c7204032d50b73a27429f3b598d9e93135e.  Thanks.

Comment: Well that's a separate question, but check its error message "UniswapV2: TRANSFER_FAILED". you can read more about the error here: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/common-errors .  Please post a new question if you have new questions